# Xcode Organizer: "Your team has no devices for which to generate a provisioning profile."

Tags: xcode, ios-provisioning

I am experiencing a strange error in Xcode's Organizer. I have two team members and whenever we log in we receive the following message:

> Your team has no devices for which to generate a provisioning
>   profile. Please connect a device to use for development, or manually
>   add a Device ID using the Provisioning Portal.
>   https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios

If I go there I can clearly see two devices, and two certificates for the two developers. In fact, I can even build and install on my device fine with the team provisioning profile, but for some reason I still see this error every time Organizer chooses to refresh. Can someone explain this?

Comment: I see a similar error but with the text "Your team has no devices for which to generate a provisioning profile. Please connect a device to use for development, or manually add a Device ID using the 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles' section in Member Center. https://developer.apple.com/account"

Answer (score 9):

Here's a great answer to this issue at the bottom of this forum thread: https://devforums.apple.com/message/637101#637101

The short answer is, you get the above error if you haven't added your Mac to the Portal.

"After going to the 'My Mac' device in the sidebar, and clicking 'Add to Portal', I no longer get this error."

This solution worked for me as well, since I bought a new Retina MacBook Pro.

Comment: where to search it in 2023?

Answer (score 2):

Restarting XCode fixed precisely this problem for me.  On restart, XCode downloaded the 4.1 firmware correctly and installed it.

Answer (score 1):

I was using an iPhone 3GS to try to test an application on my Mac Pro.  I kept getting the problem even after restarting Xcode 4.3.2 and removing provisioning profiles.  I tried under Xcode 4.4 with Mountain Lion on a MacBook Air and Xcode complained that "Xcode cannot run using the selected device.  Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device." I added armv6 to the projects "Architectures" and was able to start debugging on my device.  The iPhone 3GS was running iOS 4.2.1.  I'm not sure if this is unrelated to the problem but this is what I did on my Mac Pro after I saw that things were okay on my MacBook Air.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "error" means:

> Xcode can't automatically provision this device *because it's already listed in a provisioning profile*.

In other words, something did fail—*automatic* provisioning—but it doesn't matter because *manual* provisioning was the source of the failure.

So just click OK and move along. There's nothing to see here.

Answer (score -1):

We had the same problem. Deleting all certificates, removing all devices from the provisioning portal and registering them again (manually or with Xcode) fixed the problem.

Comment: There should be no reason to do all that work. If you read around, there are way better ways to fix this issue.