# in flutter, xcode Archive failed. xcode dont recognize my team and device

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

my flutter app works at ios, and android both simulators. but It failed when I do archive. (in xcode, product > archive)

I already maked apple developer account, and register my team and bundle id but xcode said they dont recognize that. :< what's wrong with this situation?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774379/xcode-organizer-your-team-has-no-devices-for-which-to-generate-a-provisioning